# Lenovo ideapad s205 suspend/hibernate problem

Tags: 11.10, lenovo, ideapad

I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop. At first the Wifi didn't work so I ran

```
rfkill unblock wifi
rfkill unblock all
modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

Now the Wifi works, however when I try to Suspend/Hibernate the computer. It gets stuck. 
What should I do?

**Update** 
Whenever I try to run pm-hibernate, the computer goes into hibernation for a split second and comes back.

Comment: The Suspend works in fedora 15, maybe this is because it uses systemd instead of upstart?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Just noticed that the `acer_wmi` module doesn't really have much to do with your suspend problem - more than it's blocking suspend. If you find the module responsible for blocking suspend, just switch out  its name with `acer_wmi` in the following suggestions, but without finding the responsible module, my suggestions probably aren't going to help you too much.

---

The traditional way of troubleshooting suspend where there's a known driver issue is to force the unloading of that module before suspend. You'd do that by running

```
sudoedit /etc/default/acpi-support
```

And looking for the `MODULES=""` line and changing it to (in your case):

```
MODULES="acer_wmi"
```

But reading the comments at the top of `/etc/default/acpi-support`, I'm not sure that's still going to work. Give it a go.

If it doesn't, you might find a short script like this fixes things:

```
#!/bin/sh

rmmod acer_wmi
pm-hibernate
modprobe acer_wmi
```

That will need to be run as root, so whereever you save it, you'll want to run it like: `sudo bash ~/my-suspend-script`.

I feel like there should be a good way to hack this into the `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` system but I don't know enough about it to say conclusively. Perhaps something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

case $1 in
     suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
        rmmod acer_wmi
        ;;
     resume|thaw)
        modprobe acer_wmi
        ;;
esac
```

That would be cleanest in terms of integration if editing `acpi-support` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `tlp` package fixed any problems I had with suspend on my Lenovo S205.

[credit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1531105/comments/30)

Comment: indeed -- time to delete our comments :)